# Edges of each colour for Ramsey Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Consider a 2-coloring of the edges of a complete graph $K_{n}$. Assume it doesn't exhibit a monochromatic subgraph of $m$ vertices thus demonstrating that the Ramsey number $R(m,m)$ is greater than $n$. In the case that $R(m,m)$ is in fact $n+1$ (call such a colouring a "maximal" Ramsey graph) can we say that the number of edges of each colour in the graph are equal? I have in mind the graph on 5 vertices with all edges round the perimeter red and all internal edges blue, but I wonder if such a symmetry continues for $R(4,4)$ or even unknown Ramsey numbers like $R(5,5)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It continues at least for $R(4,4)$; the unique coloring of $K_{17}$ (which I found [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/ramsey.html)) has $68$ red and $68$ blue edges. Past that point, we don't know enough to say for sure.

If this color parity were a known fact in general, it would imply that $K_{R(m,m)-1}$ has an even number of edges, which limits $R(m,m)$ to $1$ or $2$ modulo $4$. Such a limitation would let us reduce the range of possible values of $R(5,5)$ considerably: we currently have $43 \le R(5,5) \le 48$, but this would tell us that $45 \le R(5,5) \le 46$.

(I don't believe that smarter people than me would have missed this, so I conclude that there is no proof that color parity should hold.)

We *do* have strong reason to believe that the red and blue edges should be approximately balanced. (Beyond just reasons of fairness.) A theorem of Erdős and Szemerédi says that if a coloring of $K_{n}$ is unbalanced (more than a $\frac12+\epsilon$ fraction of the edges are blue, say) then the known guarantee that there's a monochromatic clique of order $\frac12\log_2 n$ can be improved to $(\frac12+\delta)\log_2 n$ for some $\delta>0$ (depending on $\epsilon$).

This doesn't mean anything for the actual Ramsey-maximal graphs, because maybe that lower bound is far from the truth (our upper bounds look more like $2\log_2 n$), but it's very suggestive.

---

It's worth noting that in other symmetric Ramsey problems, a symmetry between the colors does not always exist. For example, consider $R(P_{2k}, P_{2k})=3k-1$. An extremal construction here has $K_{2k-1,k-1}$ in red (so that we can't get a path longer than $2k-1$ because we run out of vertices on one side) and colors everything else blue (which can't get a path longer than $2k-1$ because it's stuck on one side of the red bipartite graph). This is not balanced: it is about $5/9$ blue.

Comment: A very thorough and persuasive response, thanks!